# Internal Server Error 500 Codeigniter on upload to webhosting

Tags: php, web-services, codeigniter

I am facing server 500 error on following website, fabcoders.com/ghostwriter

- Login in as username: chelsea Password:Chelsea123
- once logged in you'll be directed to http://fabcoders.com/ghostwriter/dashboard page.
- There you'll find a listing as topic,submission,view click the view link.
- You'll be directed to http://fabcoders.com/ghostwriter/project/view_submission/230 page click the view. and that that is were i get the 500 error. It show blank but once you inspect element and go to console there you can see the error.

The code is in codeigniter
Here is the controller section

```
public function view_submission_detail ($submission_id)
    {   
        $user_id = $this->session->userdata("id");
        $this->load->model("submission_m");
        $this->load->model("ratings_m");

        $star = $this->input->post("rating");
        $review=$this->input->post("reviews");
        $tip=$this->input->post("tip");


    $record  = $this->submission_m->get($submission_id);
    $rat_to=$record->fk_user_id;
    //dump($record);
    $select = $this->ratings_m->get($rat_to);
    //$tip=$select->tip;


    $this->load->model("addproject_m");
    $temp = $this->user_m->get($rat_to);


    $emailid = $temp->email;
    $user_id = $temp->id;
    $prjct = $this->addproject_m->get($record->fk_project_id); 
    //dump($record->fk_project_id);
    //dump($prjct);
    $pname = $prjct->p_title;
    $buyername = $prjct->p_buyname;
    $this->data['tip'] = $tip;
    $this->data['numele'] = count($this->submission_m->viewusersub($user_id));
    $this->data['numacc'] = count($this->submission_m->viewuseracc($user_id));
    $this->data['numrej'] = count($this->submission_m->viewuserreject($user_id));
    $this->data['numrew'] = count($this->submission_m->viewuserrewrite($user_id));
    //$this->data['usersubs'] = $this->submission_m->viewusersub($user_id);

    $get_rating_count=$this->submission_m->get_rating_count($rat_to);//rating_m
    $this->data['get_rating_count']=$get_rating_count;

    $get_rating_details=$this->submission_m->get_rating_details($rat_to);//rating_m
    $this->data['get_rating_details']=$get_rating_details;
    $sum=0;
    foreach($get_rating_details as $rows)
    {
    $sum=$sum+$rows->rating;
    }
    $average_rating=0;
    if($get_rating_count != 0)
    $average_rating=(int)($sum/$get_rating_count);

    if($this->input->post("accept") && $this->input->post("pk_submission_id")){
         redirect('dashboard');

    }else if($this->input->post("reject") && $this->input->post("pk_submission_id")){
        $this->submission_m->reject_submission($submission_id);
        $this->submission_m->rejectMail($emailid,$pname,$buyername);                    
        redirect('dashboard');

    }else if($this->input->post("rewrite") && $this->input->post("pk_submission_id")){
        $this->submission_m->rewrite_submission($submission_id);
        $this->submission_m->rewriteMail($emailid,$pname,$buyername);   
        redirect('dashboard');
    }
    $this->data['average_rating']=$average_rating;
    $this->data['submission'] =  $this->submission_m->get($submission_id);
    $this->data['username'] = $this->user_m->get($this->data['submission']->fk_user_id);
    $this->data['project'] =  $this->addproject_m->get($this->data['submission']->fk_project_id);
    $this->load->view('project/view_submission_details', $this->data);
}
```

Here is the view part
        
            
                p_title ?> 
        img/close.png">
            
                
                Writer's Name:

firstname ?>

Submitted Date:

created))); ?>

Rating:

```
                </li><?php if($tip!= ""){?>
                <li class="label-list">Tip for Writer:</li>
                <li><?php echo $tip; } ?></li>

                <br>
                <?php if($numele>=1)
                    echo "Previous submissions";?>
                <br>
                <?php if($numele>=1)
                    echo "Number of submissions ".$numele;?>
                <br>
                <?php if($numacc>=1)
                    echo "Number of Projects Accepted ".$numacc;?>
                <br>
                <?php if($numrej>=1)
                    echo "Number of Projects Rejected ".$numrej;?>
                <br>
                <?php if($numrew>=1)
                    echo "Number of Projects Rewritten ".$numrew;?>
                <br>
                <? } ?>
                <?php //echo "Tip".$get_rating_details->tip ?>

            </ul>


        <div class="content1 div-center2 colorwhite">
            <p class="text-content"><?php echo nl2br( htmlentities($submission->content)) ?></p>
                            </div>

            <div class="buttons">
            <ul class="button-row">


            <?php if(!($project->p_complete==1) && ($submission->status=='NOT REVIEWED')) { ?>
                <?php 
                echo form_open('','id="contentForm"');
                echo form_hidden("pk_submission_id",$submission->pk_submission_id);

                echo " ".form_submit("accept","Accept",'class="btn-green .btn-small" id="acceptBtn"');
                echo " ".form_submit("reject","Reject",'class="btn-red .btn-small"');
                echo " ".form_submit("rewrite","Rewrite",'class="btn-blue .btn-small"');

                echo form_close();
                ?>

                <?php } ?>

            </ul>

    </body>
    </html>
    <script>
            $(function() {

                $("#acceptBtn").click(function(e){
                    var sdata = $('#contentForm').serialize();
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "<?php echo site_url('project/accept_submission'); ?>",
                        type: "POST",
                        data:sdata +'&accept=1',
                        success: function(data){
                            $('.buttons').remove();  
                            $('#baseModal-xs .modal-content').html(data);   
                            $('#baseModal-xs').modal("show");   

                        }
                    });
                    return false;
                });
            });

            </script>
```

- It works locally but it does not run when live the project is still in development stage.
- I don't know much about servers cause i only do coding, but in my company i was told to fix the issue and i have no clue my week end is going to be ruined :(
- I had previously posted regarding the same issue but it was for different section even that was not fixed.
- I don't know if the model part also can cause issue but i cant put the code cause i have passed to limit of the question size

Comment: there are no errors on the website, if there is any check for file rights and permissions, php version and logs

Comment: There is on click of  http://fabcoders.com/ghostwriter/project/view_submission/230 click on view there you'll find the error. you have to inspect element and in console you'll find the error.

Comment: check file permissions and post your .htaccess file here, is this website hosted on a cpanel server? if so check error log from the cpanel.

Comment: it is in ftp server. And here is the .htaccess code RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php?/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+) index.php?/$1 [L]         But Does the .htaccess affect only 1 file where as other section are working fine? or does .htaccess file also check the levels of the url path cause this is the longest level in path in the project.

Comment: If you can't get access to the error log you may need to do debugging by commenting out blocks of code until you can narrow down the error. It's likely a call to a module that is not available on the production server.

Comment: @Tristan i did as you said it is in the view part and it worked. You are a rockstar thanks a lot. I had added a extra closing brace which was causing the error.

Comment: @tristan can you take a look at my previous post and see if anything can be done to fix it??

Comment: You may need to do the same thing to find the bug in relation to your previous post.

Answer (score 0):

In the view part i had added a extra closing brace which had no opening brace i removed that brace and Wa-lah it worked :).

Comment: Fellow reviewers: this _is_ an answer. It's the OP telling us what solved it for them.